# Doesn't [d] after all that time deserve some color too?

Tags: feature-request, tags, syntax-highlighting

[d](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d) currently doesn't have any automatic syntax-highlighting.

After a good five years, isn't it time to change that?
Default-highlighting seems to work acceptably well.

While we are at it, let's do the same for the version-tags [d1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d1) and [d2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d2).

Comment: There's a joke in here, but I think I'm going to leave it where it's at...

Comment: Hm ... what ? ?

Comment: I can't.  I *mustn't*.

Comment: Unfortunately, `[d]` is not on the [list of supported languages](https://github.com/google/code-prettify#for-which-languages-does-it-work) for the syntax highlighter.

Comment: *Applauds @Will for incredible restraint.*

Comment: @BilltheLizard: Presumably, that's why Deduplicator suggested using the default highlighter.

Comment: @NathanTuggy I don't know what that means. Can someone link to an example?

Comment: @BilltheLizard: [Sure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060185/d-aws-api-authorization-is-not-working). Per revision history, without highlighting hint, nothing is colored; with `lang-default`, it colors in some half-decent semblance of actual D syntax.

Comment: I suggest using purple for highlighting the [d].

Comment: @DamienH I'd suggest pink, personally.

Comment: Hm. [d1] and [d2] are D versions and [d3] is for d3.js

Comment: Thanks a lot @Will, people are already making juvenile [d] jokes because of you. I see some people never grow up after high school :P

Comment: @Will well not making a joke about it and pointing this out is some kind of a meta joke?